# Accessing $firebaseObject Keys

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple angularfire query using a $firebaseObject like the following:

```
var obj = $firebaseObject($firebaseRef.accounts.orderByChild('user_id').equalTo("123"));
```

The object returned in $loaded looks like the following:

```
{$$conf: Object, $id: "accounts", $priority: null, -KEa4maSq8fCB52DNEM9: {user_id: "123", email: "test"}}
```

My question is how do I access for example the email key without knowing the object key -KEa4maSq8fCB52DNEM9? Is my $firebaseObject use incorrect?

Comment: console.log(obj.email);

Comment: @AndréKool that return undefined for me

Comment: Did you put it directly under getting the firebase object? Because that will return undefined because it is an asynchronous method. Try obj.$loaded(function () { 
console.log(obj.email); })

Comment: Here is what I'm using. Both return undefined. I should mention I'm using the latest angularfire lib.       obj.$loaded(function(account) {console.log(obj.email); console.log(account.email);
     });

Comment: @StevenGlasser  did u find any solution for this? I have similar problem here

Comment: @StevenGlasser If I use forEach after $loaded for my firebaseObject I can access my object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $firebaseObject, you can use $firebaseArray :

```
var obj = $firebaseArray($firebaseRef.accounts.orderByChild('user_id').equalTo("123"));
```

then you should return the promise like this:

```
obj.$loaded().then(function(){
return obj[0];
});
```